# Dart cannot break out of loop while inside awaited then callback

Tags: flutter, loops, dart

I'm trying to generate random int and check if the integer is exists in Firebase database, and do this infinitly until the integer is not exist inside database.

Below my code:

```
while (true) {
  _changeRandomInt()
  firebaseFirestore.collection("myCollection").doc(_randomInt).get().then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
  if (getFromFirebase(documentSnapshot) == null) {
    break;
  }
  });
}
```

But I cannot even run this code. Error: `A break statement can't be used outside of a loop or switch statement. Try removing the break statement.` I have my break inside while loop, then why I'm getting this error? How to fix this?

Comment: in your case `break` is inside future then, try with `return`

Comment: use `Future.doWhile` method - the docs say: *"Performs an operation repeatedly until it returns false.

The operation, action, may be either synchronous or asynchronous."*

Answer (score 2):

> A break statement can't be used outside of a loop or switch statement. Try removing the break statement.

This is self explanatory. You can't use break outside of a loop. Which in your case is inside a future.

Do something like this:

```
_changeRandomInt();
firebaseFirestore.collection("myCollection").doc(_randomInt).get()
    .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {

    while (getFromFirebase(documentSnapshot) != null){
        //the body of this loop will only execute as long as the value isn't null
        //will break out of the loop as soon as the value is null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `break` you have used is inside `then()`, which means no loop is available immediately above `break. You can refactor your code in this manner to get it working.

```dart
while (true) {
  _changeRandomInt()
  final documentSnapshot = await firebaseFirestore.collection("myCollection").doc(_randomInt).get();
  if (getFromFirebase(documentSnapshot) == null) {
    break;
  }
}
```

If `getFromFirebase` is also a future, then await that as well inside if block.

Comment: But isn't this inefficient? It's calling and awaiting for the same future again and again until it encounters null. Perhaps calling the awaited function once and then traversing the values until null in the result is more efficient.

Comment: It depends on what is it you are trying to achieve. There's also a `firstWhere` method you can look into, which can solve such cases without using an infinite loop with a break statement. https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.3/dart-core/Iterable/firstWhere.html

Comment: Thanks. This method was not known to me.

Answer (score 1):

You want to do something like this:

```
void functionName() async {
  try{
    var ans;
    while(getFromFirebae(ans)== null){
     ans = await firebaseFirestore.collection("myCollection").doc(_randomInt).get();
    
    }
  } catch(e){
    //error
  }
}
```

However, this is not the correct way. A good practice is to create a loading widget, that would show an animation while the future is loading. An even better way - to load everything in the background without stalling the overall app.

Answer (score 0):

Some people have been saying that you're using "`break` inside a `Future`", but that's not quite right.  Your problem is that you're using `break` *inside* of a separate function body.  This is equivalent to writing:

```dart
void f() {
  break;
}
```

which doesn't make sense since `break` is not used directly within a *local* loop or `switch` statement.  It doesn't matter that you're creating your function within a loop; `break` and `continue` statements perform *local* control flow (within a function), not across functions.

In general, instead of using `Future.then`, you should prefer using `async`/`await` which will have the compiler generate the callback function *with appropriate code transformations* for you:

```dart
while (true) {
  _changeRandomInt()

  var documentSnapshot =
    await firebaseFirestore.collection("myCollection").doc(_randomInt).get();
  if (getFromFirebase(documentSnapshot) == null) {
    break;
  }
}
```

Note that performing an asynchronous operation continuously in a loop isn't very efficient, so you probably should consider alternative approaches if possible, however.